# How to Search in Notepad++ but exclude variations

Tags: notepad++

Does anybody know if I can do the following type of search in Notepad++ please ?

Find "league" but ignore/exclude "myleague" & "leagues" ...

Thanks in advance, hopefully :-)

Comment: Match whole word only-worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Use option "match whole words" or use regex `\bleague\b`.